# AWS Cloudwatch: how to fetch custom metrics from AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using latest version of AWS SDK for JavaScript.

I need to get some metrics from AWS Cloudwatch with **getMetricStatistics** method (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatch.html#getMetricStatistics-property). To use this method, you need to specify **Dimensions** field.

It works fine if I specify dimensions like this:

```
{Name: 'InstanceId', Value: SOME_INSTANCE_ID_HERE}
```

But with Elastic Beanstalk you can't rely on InstanceId, because it might create/destroy instances when it needs. So I tried to use different dimension:

```
{Name: 'InstanceName', Value: NAME_FROM_ELB}
```

But it doesn't work. I'm trying to find another way/dimension to access ELB metrics.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but you might also want to cross post this to: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got a reply from AWS: there is no way to do it, you have to use InstanceId as a dimension. You can get it dynamically using [EC2 metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html).